# Error deploying EAR in JBoss AS 7.1build using ANT

Tags: java, deployment, ant, jboss, jboss7.x

I am having a problem with deploying my application on JBoss AS 7.1 . We are now migrating from JBoss AS 4 to JBoss AS 7.1 but facing trouble due to different module structure of JBoss AS 7.1 . While deploying our EAR in standalone mode of JBoss AS 7.1 we get below error log. Please suggest what we are doing wrong.. I am copying server log below.

```
15:12:24,868 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."Shrisurance.ear"."Shrisurance.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."Shrisurance.ear"."Shrisurance.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "Shrisurance.war" of deployment "Shrisurance.ear"
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error getting reflective information for class com.shrisure.server.OnlinePolicyRedirectURL with ClassLoader ModuleClassLoader for Module "deployment.Shrisurance.ear.Shrisurance.jar:main" from Service Module Loader
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:70) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.ee.metadata.MethodAnnotationAggregator.runtimeAnnotationInformation(MethodAnnotationAggregator.java:58)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.handleAnnotations(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:85)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:70)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:55)
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/IsSerializable
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2291) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1743) [rt.jar:1.6.0_25]
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.ClassReflectionIndex.<init>(ClassReflectionIndex.java:57) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentReflectionIndex.getClassIndex(DeploymentReflectionIndex.java:66) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable from [Module "deployment.Shrisurance.ear.Shrisurance.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
... 15 more

15:12:24,890 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
15:12:24,891 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started (with errors) in 3526ms - Started 190 of 279 services (4 services failed or missing dependencies, 84 services are passive or on-demand)
15:12:25,091 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "Shrisurance.ear" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"Shrisurance.ear\".\"Shrisurance.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"Shrisurance.ear\".\"Shrisurance.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment \"Shrisurance.war\" of deployment \"Shrisurance.ear\""}}
15:12:25,099 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015871: Deploy of deployment "jboss-deployment-structure.xml" was rolled back with no failure message
15:12:25,104 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7)      JBAS015877: Stopped deployment jboss-deployment-structure.xml in 4ms
15:12:25,110 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment Shrisurance.har in 17ms
15:12:25,120 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment Shrisurance.jar in 27ms
15:12:25,576 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment Shrisurance.war in 483ms
15:12:25,580 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment Shrisurance.ear in 488ms
15:12:25,581 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2)         JBAS014774: Service status report
 JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.subunit."Shrisurance.ear"."Shrisurance.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."Shrisurance.ear"."Shrisurance.war".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "Shrisurance.war" of deployment "Shrisurance.ear"

15:12:25,584 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS014654: Composite operation was rolled back
15:12:25,585 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.subunit.\"Shrisurance.ear\".\"Shrisurance.war\".POST_MODULE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit.\"Shrisurance.ear\".\"Shrisurance.war\".POST_MODULE: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment \"Shrisurance.war\" of deployment \"Shrisurance.ear\""}}}}
15:13:15,758 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS011942: Stopping OSGi Framework
15:13:15,763 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-1) Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http--127.0.0.1-8085
15:13:15,765 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-1) Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http--127.0.0.1-8085
15:13:15,768 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-7) Container org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/] has not been started
15:13:15,770 WARN  [org.jboss.remoting.remote] (Remoting "svschndt682olr:MANAGEMENT" read-1) JBREM000205: Failed to accept a connection: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
```

Comment: Looks like it's missing the GWT libraries. Are they in your WAR/WEB-INF/lib directory?

Comment: Thanks for the reply and yes I have GWT libraries in the lib folder. do i require to add them anywhere in the JBoss AS 7.1 directories as well?

Comment: They just need to be accessible to the deployment. Having them in the lib directory is probably best.